# build jdk 12 error BitMap index out of bounds

Tags: java, c++

```
=== Output from failing command(s) repeated here ===
* For target jdk__packages_attribute.done:
# To suppress the following error report, specify this argument
# after -XX: or in .hotspotrc:  SuppressErrorAt=/bitMap.cpp:178
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (/home/lx/my_jdk/jdk-jdk-12-ga/src/hotspot/share/utilities/bitMap.cpp:178), pid=49485, tid=49495
#  assert(index < _size) failed: BitMap index out of bounds
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (12.0) (fastdebug build 12-internal+0-adhoc.lx.jdk-jdk-12-ga)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (fastdebug 12-internal+0-adhoc.lx.jdk-jdk-12-ga, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, serial gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x7507cb]  BitMap::verify_index(unsigned long) const+0x2b
   ... (rest of output omitted)

* All command lines available in /home/lx/my_jdk/jdk-jdk-12-ga/build/linux-x86_64-server-fastdebug/make-support/failure-logs.
=== End of repeated output ===
```

environment:
virtualBox 7.0、Ubuntu server 22.04、openjdk 11
my virtual machine memory is 10GB

compiler command:

bash configure --enable-debug 
--with-jvm-variants=server 
--disable-warnings-as-errors 
--with-extra-cflags='-fcommon'

make images

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What are you trying to do? Images of what? Why are you using JDK which is a short live version end of life years ago?